# problem in reading index columns in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm reading a csv file in pandas. It is showing correct number of rows and columns when I'm printing df.shape but when I'm trying to drop certain columns it is showing error as the column names are not defined. Here is my code:

```
  df = pd.read_csv('Weather_data.csv',sep=',',header=0,parse_dates=["datetime_utc"])
  print(df.columns)
  print(df.head())
  print(df.shape)
```

It is printing as (98913, 20)
and when I'm trying to drop columns it is showing error

```
  df.drop(columns=['_fog','_hail','_rain','_snow','_thunder','_tornado','_wdire','_windchillm','_wgustm'],axis=1,inplace=True])
```

This is the key error which is being raised:

```
KeyError: "['_fog' '_hail' '_rain' '_snow' '_thunder' '_tornado' '_wdire'\n '_windchillm' '_wgustm'] not found in axis"
```

kindly tell why this is happening
result of df.columns:

```
Index(['datetime_utc', ' _conds', ' _dewptm', ' _fog', ' _hail',
       ' _heatindexm', ' _hum', ' _precipm', ' _pressurem', ' _rain', '_snow',
       ' _tempm', ' _thunder', ' _tornado', ' _vism', ' _wdird', ' _wdire',
       ' _wgustm', ' _windchillm', ' _wspdm'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: can you show result of `print(df.columns)`

Comment: yes sure, I had uploaded it above

Comment: you see the problem, the columns you are trying to remove are not in the `df`

Comment: Your column names have leading spaces. `' _fog' != '_fog'`. Try `strip()` on your column names first, or add the leading spaces to your `columns=` in the `drop()`

Answer (score 0):

Specifying both labels and index or columns will raise a ValueError.
So for eg use either "df.drop(['B', 'C'], axis=1)" or
df.drop(columns=['B', 'C']) . hope this will help

Comment: Plz share the result image along with the code i mentioned earlier